# WKWebview not able to load dynamic url

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, wkwebview, mobile-development

I'm trying to set up DeepLinks on my webview app and it's almost done but I've ran into a final obstacle.

At the moment my code is working as follows:

I have a function declared in SceneDelegate that is triggered when the user clicks the deep link and then proceeds to "clean" the link which is only removing the "myappname://" from the start of it.

```
        func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
            guard let firstUrl = URLContexts.first?.url else {
                return
            }
            
            let originalString = firstUrl.absoluteString
            let desiredString = originalString.components(separatedBy: "sports://").last
            g_url = desiredString
            let notificationName = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "deepLink")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
        }
    }
```

It then proceeds to store the String containing the link in a variable that is declared at the top as: `var g_url: String?`
And sends a notification alert that my ViewController catches and calls the function to handle the deepLink

```
    @objc func updateUrl(){
        let new_url = SceneDelegate.shared?.g_url
        if(new_url != nil){
            let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: new_url!)!)
            self.webView.load(request)
        }
    }
```

Where it simply loads that link to the webview.

This is where my problem lies, when it tries to load the link it throws this error:

```
WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, isMainFrame=1, domain=WebKitErrorDomain, code=101, isMainFrame=1
```

The problem I think has something to do with the way the String is being encoded or handled, especially since if I use the exact same url but hard code it into the request it works with no issue.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would really appreciate some help, thank you :)

Comment: I think that the resulting of removing the url scheme does not gives a valid url. You need to add something like « someschene://» at the beginning to have a valid url.

Answer (score -1):

Found out it was due to an error from the deeplink simulator, RocketSim, that for some reason removed the double quotes from "https://" sending it as "https//" which when used in the webView.load() method throws an error because the URL wasn't valid.

Comment: That's nice but it does not emerge from the info provided in the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).